# I need a more detailed understanding of precisely how cookies work

Tags: javascript, http, cookies, browser, http-headers

I can build a full stack app using Ruby on Rails, JavaScript, React, HTML and CSS. Yet, I feel I don't understand completely how cookies actually work and what they are precisely. Below I write what I think they are, and ask that someone confirm or correct what is written.

- An HTTP request contains an HTTP method, a path, the HTTP protocol version, headers, and a body.
- An HTTP response contains the HTTP protocol version, a status code, a status message, headers, and a body.
- Both are simply text (which means that they are simply sequences of encoded characters), but when this text is parsed it contains useful structure. **Is there one single structure that an HTTP request is usually parsed into (an array, a hash)? What about an HTTP response?**
- Cookies represent some content associated with a specific header in an HTTP request, specifically the "Cookie" header.
- When building an HTTP response, the server sets the 'Set-Cookie' header. This header needs the following information: a name for the cookie, a path, and the actual content of the cookie. The path is a description of the range of URLs for which this cookie should be sent from client to server.
- Does the browser keep a list of cookies (ie, a list of elements that are each text of some sort), and it only sends the right ones to the right sites (say a google cookie to google.com)?
- Let's say I visit site A and then site B and authenticate on both. Session management just adds a specific element in the cookies (perhaps a hash named Session inside another hash that corresponds to the totality of the cookie stored in Cookie), correct? How do sites alter my cookies? Do they append new information, do they ask my browser to append information?

Comment: You may want to read [RFC 6265](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6265).

Answer (score 1):

A cookie is a string (with a specific format) that your browser stores. It can be set by a server when it sends a http-response, by the 'Set-Cookie' header. Each http-request that your browser sends that matches the cookie's path will contain that cookie in the 'Cookie' header.

The server cannot tell the browser to append data to the cookie. It can only get the current cookie value, add to it the new information, and then reset it.